# Datatables - sorting by and pagination

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fresh, but I'm learning with the help of people like you :). I need to do a table on my site that will display sorted data by type and pagination. I thought to use this solution: https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

But honestly, I do not know how to do this. Can someone give an example along with html how to do it? Or suggest a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of you need to import some of the necessary files:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

CSS :

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then using the id attribute of the table you have created use the following code :

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable(); // this creates a table object of the DataTable class
// myTable is the id of the table you have created
table.clear().draw();
table.destroy();

$.ajax({
    url: 'abc.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {value:value},//value you want to send to backend
    dataType: 'json',

    success:function(result){
        $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            "pageLength": 10, // does pagination providing 10 records per page
            "destroy": true,
            "language": {
                    "zeroRecords": "No Data Found",
                    "infoEmpty": "No Data Found",
                },
        "ajax": "objects.txt",
        // Data from backend is sent to objects.txt file in JSON format
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Key value from backend for 1st column in table" },
                { "data": "Key value from backend for 2nd column in table" },
                { "data": "Key value from backend for 3rd column in table" },
                { "data": "Key value from backend for 4th column in table"},
                { "data": "Key value from backend for 5th column in table" },
                { "data": "Key value from backend for 6th column in table" }
            ]
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

You could import more datatable javascripts that can provide more functionality such as conversion of table data to pdf or export as an excel file using button datatable javascripts. You can find more related information here : https://cdn.datatables.net/